# How many Virtual machines can mount/connect to one azure file share(Storage)?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

How many Virtual machines can mount/connect to one azure file share(Storage) ?
Is there any limit quota for azure file share(Storage) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked of Azure support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many Virtual machines can mount/connect to one azure file
>   share(Storage) ?

Based on my knowledge, there is no such limit. But there is a 2000 open handles quota on a single file. Once you have 2000 open handles, you will get an error that quota is reached. Please refer to this [FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq#scale-targetslimits).

Also, you mount one file share to too many VMs, it will reduce IOPS. Max IOPS per share is 1000. All VMs share the IOPS.

The limit is easy search on Azure official document, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits).